# InitiateSystemShutdown call not working

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm writing an application that will need to reboot the Windows machine the code is running on.

There didn't appear to be an API within .NET to do this, so I looked up the the Win32 API for this and it is called InitiateSystemShutdown. The extern declaration is given below:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern bool InitiateSystemShutdown(string Machinename, string
Message, long Timeout, int ForceAppsClosed, int RebootAfterShutdown);
```

I then try to call this operating system routine with the following arguments:

```
InitiateSystemShutdown(null, null, 30, 1, 1);
```

However, this always returns false. So I call the Marshal.GetLastWin32Error method and it returns an error code of 1008. This error code's message is:

"An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist."

The code is running inside a Windows Service and is running under the Administrator account. I've tried running it as Local System and that had not effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following example in MSDN: [Displaying the Shutdown Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376861(VS.85).aspx).

You need to get the correct privileges for your thread.